# Neither --nor (inversion)

Tags: neither-nor

> Neither I can go out nor she can come to me.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? Do I need to change "inversion"?

Comment: Yes, it is grammatical but people rarely speak like that.

Comment: @Lambie What about "Neither can I go out nor can she come to me"?

Comment: I have answered your question already.

Comment: @AungThu Most people wouldn't use neither-nor in this case because the subject is different for each part.

Comment: @AungThu I believe the inverted form used in your comment is better and is certainly close, if not exactly how I would say it myself. I am British, but have no idea what difference that makes.

Comment: Perhaps like all of the other people who commented without suggesting an alternative, I would say "I cannot go and she cannot come to me either." I guess that my next favorite alternative would be "I cannot go, nor can she come to me," which which would involve a bit of inversion.

Comment: @Chaim But the word "neither" is performing an important job, of emphasis, drawing attention to the fact that there is a double problem. If you leave it out, the nuance changes to a more bland statement of fact. There is nothing wrong with your sentence but it does not convey exactly the same message as the one proposed. "Either" is not as powerful as "neither", and it does not convey negativity.

Comment: @WS2 In that case I guess one graceful solution would be a way of describing the wanted action by both parties in the same words -- "Neither she nor I can approach the other," for example. It seems awkward to use Neither/Nor construction with two independent clauses as in the question, and my little survey of the web suggests that the construction is rarely used that way.

Comment: @WS2 “Human progress is neither automatic nor inevitable.” - Martin Luther King, Jr. “… those poor spirits who neither enjoy nor suffer much…” - Theodore Roosevelt. “… neither persons nor property will be safe.” - Frederick Douglass. “Flowers are restful to look at. They have neither emotions nor conflicts.” - Sigmund Freud. “They who can give up essential liberty to obtain a little temporary safety deserve neither liberty nor safety.” - Benjamin Franklin. “[War] is only those who have neither fired a shot nor heard the shrieks and groans... War is hell.” - William Tecumseh Sherman.

Answer (score 1):

> Neither I can go out nor she can come to me.

does not sound quite right, your second offering

> Neither can I go out nor can she come to me.

is better, meaning you are *stuck where you are*.

> Neither can I go nor can she come.

is more concise, "*to her*" and "*to me*" is implied, using "*out*" confuses the issue.